# Send Email quick action on Contact

Tags: lightning-experience, contact, lightning-quickaction, system-admin

I am trying to configure send Email quick action on Contact object. Although I have set the deliverability to the All emails and enable email-to-cases, it's not showing up on the page. Why it is not showing in the record page although I added it to the page layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object-specific Send Email actions, available only on cases and you can use the case-specific Send Email action in Salesforce Classic, Lightning Experience, and Salesforce mobile app.

Unfortunately, Global Send Email actions are supported only in Lightning Experience.

[image]

Check [Quick Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_overview.htm&type=5)

Thanks,